# t-SQL greater/less than more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I'm facing a strange problem:

I have a simple table structured like below:

```
tbl1

Username | DateOfSell
  Jack     2021/04/04
  Joe      2021/04/14
  Jack     2021/05/20
  Joe      2021/04/11
  Jack     2021/05/01
```

And Anothe one with informations of the employee, number, hire date and fire date

```
tbl2

Username | Phone | DateOfStart | DateOfEnd
  Jack     02541   2010/01/01   2021/05/21
   Joe     08522   2012/06/01       NULL
```

What I need is to create a query to select the employee only if it is still working at some date.
for example in this case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 (..) 
WHERE tbl1.DateOfSell < tbl2.DateOfEnd
```

that would be ok, but I need (for SSRS purposes) to be able to check more than one date.

IF in SSRS I have a parameter with the actual day and the previos day and also the day of the past week, how can I do?

SO: today() = 2021/05/26
previous week: 2021/05/19

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 (..) 
WHERE  '2021/05/26' < tbl2.DateOfEnd
```

I want no results because now this employee is not working anymore.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 (..) 
WHERE  '2021/05/19' < tbl2.DateOfEnd
```

in this case I need results because at tat date, the employee was still working.

what if in the parameter report I put both (or more) values?

clearly I have an error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','`

Here is a way to resolve this problem?

thank you!

Comment: "a parameter with the actual day and the previos day and also the day of the past week"  I don't think a parameter can have 3 concurrent values.  Please explain this better.

Comment: It's unclear what you want: Do you want all rows from `tbl1` but only if they are within the `DateOfStart` and `DateOfEnd`, or is that irrelevant and you want only rows from `tbl1` which are on the dates specified (then how does `tbl2` come in)? Or both? The logic is not clear, expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this query could do the trick

```
declare @dtparam date = '2021-01-10'

select *
from tbl1 t1
  join tbl2 t2
    on t1.Username = t2.Username
where t2.dateOfStart <= @dtparam
  and (
    t2.DateOfEnd >= @dtparam or
    t2.DateOfEnd is null
  )
```